# tf.exe Equivalent to Deleting Added Files

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

In Visual Studio 2015 connected to a team project on TFS 2015, I can go to `Team Viewer -> Pending Changes` and I can see a list of files in my (local) workspace which are "adds" but have not yet been promoted to source control.  These are listed in a hyperlink such as `Detected: 121 add(s), 0 delete(s)`.  When I click on this link a window is opened listing all of the added files where I can `select all -> right click -> delete`

How can this be done with tf.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such option in [Tf Command-Line Utility Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(v=vs.100).aspx). The items you mentioned are Candidate Changes. If you add or remove a file outside Visual Studio, Visual Studio can detect the changes that you make and treat them as Candidate Changes. tf.exe can only detect the add/remove files inside Visual Studio.

You may try to use TFS API to achieve what you want, here is a blog should help you:

https://roadtoalm.com/2013/06/13/using-local-workspaces-promote-excluded-changes-with-tfs-2012-api/